# How to push Edittext above Keyboard in Full screen Activity

Tags: java, android

I am working with fullscreen `Activity`,

Problem is : the Keyboard hide the edit text view, I try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using on adjustPan only, and post your XML  file as well for better understanding

Comment: you can use `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout />` where you can center your edittext and place it where ever you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN );
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR);
}
```

to get Fullscreen activity,to be able to read the adjustresize

Answer (score 3):

add this in your manifest

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your manifest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

This will cause your existing layout  to occupy less space when the keyboard appears.